# string interpolation from several variables causing Expression was too complex to be solved

Tags: swift

I've a set of variables and forming an xml based string having values of those variables but it's causing expression too complex to be solved in a reasonable time and it was suggesting breaking up statement in chunks and then I'd lose the readability. Is there a better way to form large string interpolation in this manner. The output string will go to A XML parser for traversal.

```
var person1 = (first: "John", last: "Doe")
var person2 = (first: "Jane", last: "Doe")
var person3 = (first: "Jane", last: "Roe")
var person4 = (first: "Jonnie", last: "Doe")
var person5 = (first: "Janie", last: "Doe")


var persons =
"<persons>" +
    "<person first='\(person1.first)' last='\(person1.last)' />" +
    "<person first='\(person2.first)' last='\(person2.last)' />" +
    "<person first='\(person3.first)' last='\(person3.last)' />" +
    "<person first='\(person4.first)' last='\(person4.last)' />" +
    "<person first='\(person5.first)' last='\(person5.last)' />" +
"</persons>"
```

**Edit**
There could be nesting of structures, I've created a minimalistic example for the sake of brevity but loops won't work.

**Edit 2** - Probable solution I could work out is to store them in a dictionary

You can think of it as hard coded values but wanna bring structure and cleanliness while hand coding them.

```
var persons = [ //in this way structures can be nested and seems more elegant
    "<persons>",
        "<person first='\(person1.first)' last='\(person1.last)' />",
        "<person first='\(person2.first)' last='\(person2.last)' />",
    "</persons>"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this has been answered but wanted to add what I found today after struggling with this one for a while trying to generate some complex XML strings.

While this fails...

```
let xml =
    "<Start>" + 
    "<tag>\(aVariable)</tag>" + 
    "<tag>\(anotherVariable)</tag>" + //repeated a quite a few more times
    "</Start>"
```

I have solved this by specifically typing my variables. This succeeds and compiles rather quickly

```
let xml: String =
    "<Start>" + 
    "<tag>\(aVariable)</tag>" + 
    "<tag>\(anotherVariable)</tag>" + //repeated a quite a few more times
    "</Start>"
```

Comment: that's interesting, you mean by just specifying `:String` it worked, still got to test

Comment: Yep. Just by specifying the variable type it compiles quickly and without error.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given you some good solutions but here's something else to try, if you can get your data into the form of an array (or any sequence type would do):

```
let personsArray = [
    (first: "John", last: "Doe"),
    (first: "Jane", last: "Doe"),
    (first: "Jane", last: "Roe"),
    (first: "Jonnie", last: "Doe"),
    (first: "Janie", last: "Doe"),
]

let personToEntry = { 
  (first: String, last: String) in
    "<person first='\(first)' last='\(last)' />"
}

let personEntries = lazy(personsArray).map(personToEntry)

let persons =
"<persons>" + "\n\t" +
    "\n\t".join(personEntries) + "\n" +
"</persons>"

println(persons)
```

You don't have to declare all these things separately of course, you could mash the `join`, `map`, and the closure all onto one line.  But I find it's more readable to separate them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to avoid interpolation

```
var persons =
"<persons>" +
    "<person first='"+person1.first+"' last='"+person1.last+"' />" +
        "<person first='"+person2.first+"' last='"+person2.last+"' />" +
        "<person first='"+person3.first+"' last='"+person3.last+"' />" +
        "<person first='"+person4.first+"' last='"+person4.last+"' />" +
        "<person first='"+person5.first+"' last='"+person5.last+"' />" +
"</persons>"
```

Comment: interesting... I like this, this way it can work without dictionary and interpolation, while at the same type able to access vars, but there's single quote required for each attribute value, will look a bit ugly with that

Comment: yup. but i didn't understand how your data structure is nested?

Comment: will NSXMLParser will work if I pass this string to it without single quotes for it's attribute values

Comment: oh you can put in the quotes. wait i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to do this using an array:

```
    var person1 = (first: "John", last: "Doe")
    var person2 = (first: "Jane", last: "Doe")
    var person3 = (first: "Jane", last: "Roe")
    var person4 = (first: "Jonnie", last: "Doe")
    var person5 = (first: "Janie", last: "Doe")

    var people = [person1,person2,person3,person4]

    var persons = "<persons>"

    for p in people {
        persons += "<person first='\(p.first)' last='\(p.last)' />"
    }
    persons += "</persons>"
```

The other way would be to use multiple expressions (you can split it up more or less):

```
    var personsb = "<persons>"
    personsb += "<person first='\(person1.first)' last='\(person1.last)' />"
    personsb += "<person first='\(person2.first)' last='\(person2.last)' />"
    personsb += "<person first='\(person3.first)' last='\(person3.last)' />"
    personsb += "<person first='\(person4.first)' last='\(person4.last)' />"
    personsb += "<person first='\(person5.first)' last='\(person5.last)' />"
    personsb += "</persons>"
```

Comment: I think for your purpose your answer is a better one, I might leave this here nonetheless, it won't hurt if someone comes across a similar problem that's not the same

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that currently Xcode cannot handle very large expressions. To your question: I'd recommend you to use an array which you loop over generating you the string.

```
let persons : [ (first: String, last: String) ] =  [ ... ]

var personsString = "<persons>"
for (first,last) in persons
{
    personsString += "<person first=" + first + " last=" + last + "/>"
}
personsString += "</persons>"
```

Comment: we're on the same page, can we enhance this solution if each person has children, see my Edit2 please

Comment: If it has children, you need some recursive structure, e.g. make yourself a class `Person` which has the properties `firstName`, `lastName` and `children`, where `children` is an array of type `Person`. Now you can traverse this with a recursive function.